# Why do I see different methods with reflection vs browsing the source code?

Tags: java, string, reflection

My goal is to create strings from char arrays in Java. The String class has a constructor that accepts a char array and creates a new String object, this works well. However, this constructor makes a defensive copy of the char array, which I am trying to avoid.

I was browsing the source code of the String class (for Java 8, 11 and 17), and I happened to come across a package-private constructor that does exactly what I need:

```java
    /*
    * Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
    * this constructor is always expected to be called with share==true.
    * a separate constructor is needed because we already have a public
    * String(char[]) constructor that makes a copy of the given char[].
    */
    String(char[] value, boolean share) {
        // assert share : "unshared not supported";
        this.value = value;
    }
```

Since the constructor is not public, I thought I might be able to use it with reflection. However, when I try to list all the declared constructors for the String class, I don't see the above constructor:

```java
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.16.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> import java.lang.reflect.Constructor

jshell> var ctors = String.class.getDeclaredConstructors()
ctors ==> Constructor[18] { public java.lang.String(byte[]) ... ng.String(int[],int,int) }

jshell> for (Constructor<?> c: ctors) System.out.println(c)
public java.lang.String(byte[])
public java.lang.String(byte[],int,int)
public java.lang.String(byte[],java.nio.charset.Charset)
public java.lang.String(byte[],java.lang.String) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
public java.lang.String(byte[],int,int,java.nio.charset.Charset)
java.lang.String(char[],int,int,java.lang.Void)
java.lang.String(java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder,java.lang.Void)
public java.lang.String(java.lang.StringBuilder)
public java.lang.String(java.lang.StringBuffer)
java.lang.String(byte[],byte)
public java.lang.String(char[],int,int)
public java.lang.String(char[])
public java.lang.String(java.lang.String)
public java.lang.String()
public java.lang.String(byte[],int,int,java.lang.String) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
public java.lang.String(byte[],int)
public java.lang.String(byte[],int,int,int)
public java.lang.String(int[],int,int)
```

In the above output, I also see some constructors that I don't see in the source code, for example `java.lang.String(java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder,java.lang.Void)`. Can someone help me understand this behavior? Why is the list of constructors from reflection different from the ones in the source code?

I am not using any security manager, in case that influences the answer. Also using vanilla openjdk (tried on version 8, 11 and 17).

Comment: It works fine in Java 8. The constructor doesn't exist in Java 11.

Comment: Which is why programming by 'what I can find today' versus programming by 'what the documentation specifies' is bad practice.  There's a reason why access specifiers exist.

Comment: username checks out

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 separate problems.

### String does not work that way

In java8, the `j.l.String` class worked by having a backing char array. However, this is somewhat inefficient; a *lot* of strings used in JVMs across the planet, even in places that don't use the basic alphabet in daily discourse, are 100% consisting of ASCII characters. Like, 95%+ of them. And yet, strings were expending 16 bits per characters, which is painful.

So, things were changed. Now, the backing storage mechanism **is a `byte[]`**, and the string ships with a separate flag that indicates what's in that. That mechanism hasn't changed since the change (so, we're now on 'v2' of the string implementation, I guess): The only 2 storage mechanisms used are 'LATIN1', which means each character takes 1 byte, and is to be looked up in the LATIN1 table (which is ASCII with some basic stuff added like é). The other option is - it's UTF16 (or rather the java slight modification that encodes mostly the `\0` character differently). Either way, a `char[]` is useless here. At best, you could tell string to treat the data as 'java-variant UTF16' and use some *very* lowlevel ops indeed to just assign the 'pointer' to the memory location that contains your char data and now make that the byte data instead, updating the 'length' flag to indicate it's twice as long. Actually allowing this would make it rather very easy for a JVM to hard-crash (coredump), or be a security hole, so JVMs aggressively won't let you do this, and will 'police' its class files (the verifier, if it detects bytecode attempts to do this, will reject a class file).

But, even if you manage to get your char data in a byte[] array form, you're still in trouble

### Reflection is broken

This break gets progressively worse over versions. It starts in java9 with jigsaw. Now, you can still 'reflect' as usual, but, there's a separate concern of module openness which sits above reflection in the sense that the module system can separately also deny access to non-public stuff, and `.setAccessible(true)` in the reflection API doesn't change this (there is no way to override it with java code without hacks). You can dance around this by adding a bevy of very complicated `--add-opens` switches.

Using reflection to tinker with internals is being eliminated more and more with every java release.

### Software doesn't work this way

`private` exists for a reason. Whilst the jigsaw 'module' break really is a break, and OpenJDK team should (and has) taken flak for breaking contracts by doing that, the change in how `j.l.String` internally represents data is no problem at all: `private` (and package private) include the word **private** for a reason: It's a contract that states: Any future version may work *completely* differently. This may occur at any time, in a point update (so, from 1.2.3 to 1.2.4), without warning, and with zero care given to any code that depended on the private stuff being there.

You can develop like this, no problem. It just means you need to set an alert in your agenda that you check in with the openjdk commits every other month and program your software into a giant mess o switch statements or what not, as you'll be reprogramming the feature for every release, and you can't upgrade anything until you've ensured that you've checked every 'uses private stuff' hackery in your codebase. Forever. This can be worth it, but, it's a high cost to pay. It's rather unlikely that it is worth it here.

### Solutions

If you *actually* have a performance problem (that would imply you have either millions of these char arrays, or that the char array is many millions of characters in size), which I rather doubt, you have various solutions

### `CharSequence`

CharSequence is the interface that various string-esques implement, such as `StringBuilder`. You can easily write your own implementation of `CharSequence` that works directly off of a backing char array. Any code that works on CharSequence would work directly. Unfortunately, lots of code requires that you pass in an instance of `String`, which, as a final class, you can't modify or proxy.

### reflection

For now you can probably still reflect, but you'd have to change whatever code you have that ends in '... and now I have a `char[]` array'. That code needs to decide:

If on JDK9 or 10, just break (or look up when this string change was introduced, 9/10 being non-LTS versions, I wouldn't care about it).

If on JDK8 or below, make a char array and start shoving the data in here. Then use reflection to call the `(char[], true)` variant.

if on JDK11 or up, make a byte array, fill that up - LATIN1 style (1 byte per char) if possible, java-modded UTF16 style otherwise, then use the `new String(byte[] value, byte coder)` constructor (Which isn't there in JDK8 - it's one *or* the other, depending on java release), passing `LATIN1` (byte value 0) or `UTF16` (byte value 1) as needed.

### Don't use strings in the first place

`CharBuffer`, `ByteBuffer`, `java.io.Reader` and `java.io.Writer` may all be more relevant data types. This requires changing the code that *currently* produces a char array (or not - a `CharBuffer` can be made wrapped around an existing array, i.e. turning an already existing 10 million char large char[] into a CharBuffer instance is cheap), and also the code that currently requires a `String` - it would have to require one of those instead.

Comment: `java.lang` is NOT open by default. Only the packages in the `jdk.unsupported` module are open by default. Also, open or not is irrelevant for `getDeclaredConstructors`. There is a separate mechanism (reflection filtering) that I am not fond of (lying runtime), but that doesn't apply here either.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn answer slightly edited; instead of oversimplifying this part (the point isn't to explain how modules work here, just that they exist and make 'reflect your way into a non-accessible string constructor is problematic in light of the module access rules'), now it basically just says 'this will get in your way' without the detail.

Comment: For me Reflection consists of two parts: Introspection (what constructors/fields/methods does a class have) and the part where you actually call/use that. The second part can be done with the `java.lang.invoke` package as well. Modules do not mess with the first part. And this question is about introspection :)

Comment: I think you may have misread the question, @JohannesKuhn. It's clearly about both - OP wants to find the string constructor that directly 'adopts' a provided array (i.e. _does not_ copy / process the entire array - is `O(1)`), __and__ call it. The end goal is clearly not 'I want to see it', the end goal is 'I want to find it so that I can call it'.

Comment: You are confusing things. Java has a modified UTF-8 encoding used in class files and Serialization, but the UTF-16 encoding is just the standard UTF-16 encoding.